# Find the same rows and colums between two dataframes

Tags: r

I have these two data frames:

```
df_wanttobuy <- data.frame(customerid = c(1,2,3), sweet = c(1,0,1), cheese = c(1,1,0), milk = c(0,1,0), coffee = c(1,0,0))
df_not_wanttobuy <- data.frame(customerid = c(1,2,4,5), bread = c(1,0,1,0), milk = c(0,1,0,1), coffee = c(0,1,1,1))
```

How can I merge them by `customerid` and keep columns present in both dataframes setting the according to these rules:

- If the value is 0 in both dfs for a given column, make it 111111;
- If the value is 1 in both dfs for a given column, make it 999999;
- If the value is different and 1 in `df_wanttobuy`, make it 2
- If the value is different and 0 in `df_wanttobuy`, make it 3.

Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(customerid = c(1,2), milk = c(111111,999999), coffee = c(2,3))
```

Comment: I made a ton of edits to make it clearer what you want - can you confirm this is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategy using `across` in `dplyr` and using a couple of functions from stringr which can be substituted with `gsub`

```r
df_wanttobuy <- data.frame(customerid = c(1,2,3), sweet = c(1,0,1), cheese = c(1,1,0), milk = c(0,1,0), coffee = c(1,0,0))
df_not_wanttobuy <- data.frame(customerid = c(1,2,4,5), bread = c(1,0,1,0), milk = c(0,1,0,1), coffee = c(0,1,1,1))

library(tidyverse)

df_wanttobuy %>%
  inner_join(df_not_wanttobuy, by = 'customerid') %>%
  select(customerid, ends_with('.x'), ends_with('.y')) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), ~ case_when(. == get(str_replace(cur_column(), '.x', '.y')) & . == 0 ~ 111111,
                                             . == get(str_replace(cur_column(), '.x', '.y')) & . == 1 ~999999,
                                             . == 0 ~ 3,
                                             TRUE ~ 2),
                .names = '{str_remove(.col, ".x")}'), .keep = 'unused')
  customerid   milk coffee
1          1 111111      2
2          2 999999      3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

`dplyr` only version

```r
library(dplyr)

df_wanttobuy %>%
  inner_join(df_not_wanttobuy, by = 'customerid') %>%
  select(customerid, ends_with('.x'), ends_with('.y')) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), ~ case_when(. == get(gsub('.x', '.y', cur_column())) & . == 0 ~ 111111,
                                             . == get(gsub('.x', '.y', cur_column())) & . == 1 ~999999,
                                             . == 0 ~ 3,
                                             TRUE ~ 2),
                .names = '{gsub(".x", "", .col)}'), .keep = 'unused')
  customerid   milk coffee
1          1 111111      2
2          2 999999      3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @ErikBodg, that cannot be figured out without having a look on your data structure?

Answer (score 2):

I think your expected output does not match the behaviour you describe (e.g. milk should be 0 from the example data using your described behavior). This was confusing me for a while.

Anyway, here is my approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

inner_join(pivot_longer(df_wanttobuy, -customerid),
           pivot_longer(df_not_wanttobuy, -customerid),
           c("customerid", "name")) %>%
  mutate(new_value = c("00" = 2,
                       "11" = 3,
                       "01" = 111111,
                       "10" = 999999)[paste0(value.x, value.y)]) %>%
  pivot_wider(customerid, names_from = name, values_from = new_value)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  customerid  milk coffee
       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1          1     2 999999
2          2     3 111111
```

```
# Data used
df_wanttobuy <- structure(list(customerid = c(1, 2, 3), sweet = c(1, 0, 1), cheese = c(1, 1, 0), milk = c(0, 1, 0), coffee = c(1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df_not_wanttobuy <- structure(list(customerid = c(1, 2, 4, 5), bread = c(1, 0, 1, 0), milk = c(0, 1, 0, 1), coffee = c(0, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```